# Static Columns and Dynamic Rows in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm really new to *iReport* and I'm having difficulty in designing a report similar to below.
I want Bank Wire,Credit Card,Cheque,Transaction,Blue,Red,Total
to be static in that page and the  values in the column to be Dynamic. I actually have a List of Java Bean to be displayed columns wise.I was able to do it dynamically but i want the first column to be styled differently.

> ```
> Transaction      Blue      Red       Total
> ---------------+---------+---------+---------
>  Bank Wire     |     0   |    0    |     0
>  Credit Card   |     2   |    0    |     2
>  Cheque        |     1   |    0    |     1
> ------------------------------------------------
> Total All      |     3   |    0    |     3 
> --------------------------xx---------------------`
> ```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaWtdTgY3MU

Comment: the video was showing how to use tables...how do i add multiple static  rows..